Azure AD B2C: Can I use a claim value in a Metadata Item in a TechnicalProfile?
I have a TechnicalProfile like this:
<TechnicalProfile Id="ExternalDirectorySignInProfile">
    <DisplayName>Multi-Tenant AAD</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <!-- enable sign in from specific token issuers (v2.0) -->
        <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">{Claim:tokenIssuerPrefix}</Item>
        ... blah ...
    </Metadata>
    ... blah ...
</TechnicalProfile>

So I'm trying to use a Claim Resolver: {Claim:tokenIssuerPrefix} and it's having none of it:
The ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes metadata item in technical profile 'ExternalDirectorySignInProfile' of policy 'B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions_Debug' does not contain a list of comma delimited URIs

To be fair the docs only mention Claim Resolvers working "in an input or output claim".
In a previous OrchestrationStep in my policy I have called a REST service that has determined whether the user's domain name is recognised for multi-tenant AAD sign-in and has returned their tokenIssuerPrefix as a claim and I want to restrict the tenants that we'll accept authentication from to just that tokenIssuer. If there's another way, then please do tell me, otherwise I'll just have to open it to all AAD tenants

One way to restrict the tenants could be to restrict access via the ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes key.
This restricts access to a specific list of Microsoft Entra tenant users who can sign in.

I'm tempted to downvote this answer because the whole point of the question is about the ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes Key and how to set it dynamically from a claim during UserJourney execution.

Agreed, but you wanted a way to restrict the tenants, hence my suggestion,
